# Certain Printing Specifications for Folding

Tags: print-design, print-production, folding, binding

I want to be able to print on tabloid paper then fold it like a booklet but with a spine. So essentially it would have two folds so that it somewhat represents a spine. I would also want to have it stapled along the spine or folds of the spine. I was wondering if this was possible, right now I use a xerox 4112 if anyone has any ideas that would be great thanks.

The printer can fold and staple just not sure if I can customize folding.

Also my initial problem is that when I print it, the booklet along the fold bludges a lot and I want to try to make it more flat. If you have any ideas for this I would also be greatful. I print 4-6 tabloid sheets. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Book or Long Reach Staplers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001B0GWKU) are easily purchased.

As for whether your specific printer can do custom folding, you'll need to contact the manufacturer or read the manual.  That's more of a tech support question, not geared towards design.

And regarding the folded piece not being flat... rest something heavy on the copies for a day or so. They'll flatten out.